# Using Hibernate @Formula for finding time difference

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm using Hibernate @Formula to find the time difference between 2 columns

```
 @Formula("(sysdate-creation_date) * 86400")
 private long elapsedTime;
```

This gives elapsedTime in days if I run the query on Oracle but while doing unit testing using HSQL DB, it gives elapsedTime in milliSeconds. Is there any way I can make this formula work on both Oracle and HSQLDB ? For my use case , I want elapsed time in seconds

Comment: DATEDIFF doesn't work with Oracle

Comment: I would suggest to use Oracle for unit testing if target server is  oracle because you will have more issues and will waste more time with mock DB than for oracle setup. H2 might be a better choice but I did try it and decided not to use mock databases for testing anymore with or without hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

To find the time difference in seconds between 2 columns use an SQL that is supported by both.

For example, in ORA syntax compatibility mode, `MYDATE1 - MYDATE2` gives the number of days between two dates as an INTERVAL.

If you want a numeric value, cast the result as an integer or other numeric.

Comment: I'm unable to find any such SQL that is supported by both. MYDATE1 - MYDATE2 gives the number of days between two dates in Oracle but gives number of seconds as output in case of HSQLDB